# Alternative to "much more"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, vocabulary

"The enhanced images can also be fed to a machine learning algorithm for a much more reliable detection."

I wish to shorten this statement, and the prime candidate for trimming seems to be the use of "much more reliable". Can you please suggest alternatives? If you can spot any other changes, please let me know those too.

Comment: There aren't really any ways to shorten it without losing some of the meaning ("...for more reliable detection" loses the emphasis of "much", for example). Only you can decide what parts of the meaning can be omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "The enhanced images can also be fed to a machine learning algorithm for a much more reliable detection."
>
> I wish to shorten this statement

If you more want to make it more it fluent I would suggest:

> Feeding the enhanced images to a machine learning algorithm can greatly increase the detection rate.

Often you can omit words like *also*, especially in scientific papers.